# Lost HDD space at home

Tags: nautilus, hard-drive, remmina, user-space

I have total 365 GB at /home :

[image]

And 146 Gb is used:

[image]

So free space must be: 365 - 146 = 219 Gb
But it is 17.2 Gb! 
(See screen2 - it is nautilus directory properties with sudo)

201.8 Gb is "invisible". Where are free space?

Addition info

- Seems such problem was occured on Remmina (remote desctop client) runs
- Reebot was help once time. But not for now.
- Baobab on sudo also show 146.1 GB

Comment: Please include in your question the exact output of running the following commands in a terminal. `df -h /home`, `du -h --max-depth=1 /home/lost+found/`, `grep '/home' /proc/mounts` and `sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda11` (please use copy&paste and code block formatting, rather than screenshots)

Comment: `df -h /home, du -h --max-depth=1 /home/lost+found/, grep '/home' /proc/mounts` - unknown key «--max-depth=1»

Comment: Don't run all commands at once, just one by one. :) And please **edit** your question to include all new information.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/K41jY1HN - result, https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18335998/dumpe-2fs.txt - dump file (last command)